# Filtering Sales_flat_quote in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to have data from `sales_flat_quote` table where `reserved_order_id` is Null. I wrote.

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';
require_once 'cache.php';

class Mage_Migrate_Carts extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run(){
        $quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $readConnection = $quotes->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = "Select * from sales_flat_quote where reserved_order_id is Null";   
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        print_r($results);
    }
}   

$shell = new Mage_Migrate_Carts();
$shell->run();
```

It's on running this it's throwing error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in file.php on line 11` . How can I write a `sqlquery` in the sales/quote model. I have touched Magento first-time today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to need add `core/resource` to read the query.

```
public function run(){
        $quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = "Select * from sales_flat_quote where reserved_order_id is Null";   
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        print_r($results);
    }
```

Comment: what is the use of `$quotes` then if we are not using it ? when are we filtering on `$quotes`? Using your code it says `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)`

Comment: in @quotes you are calling a  magento model file.. put limit in query and check..

Comment: LIMIT 100 worked. @quotes line I commented still the code is working and the giving the same result? why ?

Comment: because second time ur limit will be LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100; or increase the memory limit..

Comment: `core/resource` will always be needed for querying ? cant we use `addAttributeToFilter` to filter?

Comment: When you are using the custom query. Other will use when you use magento model.

Comment: when I use `addAttributeToFiler` I get this error `Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object`

Comment: `$quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFiler('reserved_order_id','');` use that for model collection

Comment: Some error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()`